# nodejs firebase firestore - Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I cant find out why what is causing these errors is there any experts out there?

Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs

logs in firebase functions:

Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Function cannot be initialized.

code below

```
var serviceAccount = require("./workservices-e4506-firebase-adminsdk-gawgy-6d4c6a39a1.json");

// admin.initializeApp({
//   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
//   databaseURL: "https://workservices-e4506.firebaseio.com"
// });

admin.initializeApp();

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = require('express')();

const firebase = require('firebase');

  
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBEkSLuI3itUsX3iIhvDnnHHT7WoCT76qI",
    authDomain: "workservices-e4506.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://workservices-e4506.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "workservices-e4506",
    storageBucket: "workservices-e4506.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "232325006209",
    appId: "1:232325006209:web:da0aca044337ef4b119e80",
    measurementId: "G-K8BRW9Y8HL"
  };

//gives error when deploying
firebase.default.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);













app.get('/JobPosts', (req, res) => {
    admin.firestore().collection('JobPosts').orderBy('createdAt','desc').get()
    .then(data => {
        let jobPosts = [];
        data.forEach(doc => {


            // jobPosts.push(doc.data())

            jobPosts.push({
                jobId: doc.id,
                ...doc.data()
            });

        });
    return res.json(jobPosts);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });






app.post('/createJobPost', (req, res) => {

const newJob = {
    jobDescription: req.body.jobDescription,
    jobTitle: req.body.jobTitle,
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
};

admin.firestore().collection('JobPosts').add(newJob)
.then(docRef => {
res.json({message: `document ${docRef.id} created succesfully`})
})
.catch(err => {
    //500 server error
    res.status(500).json({error: 'something went wrong'})
    console.error(err)
})
    });





///////////////////////Lesson 5 ////////////////////////////////


//sign up route

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {

    const user = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    username:req.body.username
};


firebase.firestore().doc(`/users/${user.username}`).get()
.then((doc) => {

if(doc.exists){
    ///bad request
    return res.status(400).json({
        username: 'this username is already taken'});
} else {
    return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password)
}
})
.then((data) =>{
   return  data.user.getIdToken();

})
.then(token =>{
    // 201 status code indicates that a request was successful and as a result a resource has been created
    return res.status(201).json({ token });
})

.catch((err) => { 
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({error: err.code });
    })

});
///////////////////////Lesson 5 ////////////////////////////////


  exports.api = functions.region('australia-southeast1').https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the entire contents of your `index.js` file, you are missing the code to declare a Cloud Function. For more on how to add one, see this [minimal example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#add-the-addmessage-function) in the documentation.

Aside from that, you are trying to initialize both the Firebase Admin SDK and the client-side SDK in your file, which is both not needed and not supported. In Cloud Functions, you should only be using `firebase-admin`, so remove everything from `const firebase = require('firebase');` and below in the code you posted.

Comment: Actually the last line here declares the function using an express app.

Comment: Woops.... I complete missed the scrollbar. Thanks for catching that. That still leaves the two SDKs though, which I suspect is part of the problem.